# Supply missing values via query in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my MySQL database that I query from. I'm querying the date and the number of sales in a particular month. My query looks like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(time,'%b-%y') AS "date", COUNT(*) AS "value"
FROM table
WHERE time_in BETWEEN concat('2014-01-01',' 00:00:00') AND concat('2014-11-25',' 23:59:59')
GROUP BY month(time);
```

Note: I know that the concat in this case is completely unnecessary, I replace them to "?" in my PHP backend for data binding.

The result of this query looks like this as a JSON:

```
[
{"date":"Feb-14","value":"2"},
{"date":"Mar-14","value":"1"},
{"date":"May-14","value":"1"},
{"date":"Jun-14","value":"1"},
{"date":"Jul-14","value":"2"},
{"date":"Sep-14","value":"1"},
{"date":"Oct-14","value":"1"},
{"date":"Nov-14","value":"1"}
]
```

As you can see, I have missing months (January, April, etc). My question is, is there a way that these missing months can be supplied via query and populated with a value of 0? I want my output to look like this:

```
[
{"date":"Jan-14","value":"0"},
{"date":"Feb-14","value":"2"},
{"date":"Mar-14","value":"1"},
{"date":"Apr-14","value":"0"},
{"date":"May-14","value":"1"},
{"date":"Jun-14","value":"1"},
{"date":"Jul-14","value":"2"},
{"date":"Aug-14","value":"0"},
{"date":"Sep-14","value":"1"},
{"date":"Oct-14","value":"1"},
{"date":"Nov-14","value":"1"}
]
```

Comment: Have a table (or sub query) to generate the list of months. You then left join that against your current table of data and change COUNT(*) to COUNT(id) (where id is a field on your data table). Counting a field name counts the non null rows of that table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on my comment you can do something like this:-

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL month_cnt.iCnt MONTH), '%b-%y') AS MonthYear, COUNT(id)
FROM
(SELECT 0 iCnt UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11) month_cnt
LEFT OUTER JOIN table
ON MONTH(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL month_cnt.iCnt MONTH)) = MONTH(table.time_in)
AND YEAR(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL month_cnt.iCnt MONTH)) = YEAR(table.time_in)
GROUP BY MonthYear
```

This has a sub query that returns the numbers 0 to 11. It then joins this sub query against you table of data based on the month of the data being the same as the month of the current date minus the number returned by the sub query. Then it counts the records that exist on the table for that month / year

Comment: Wow, @Kickstart! This is amazing, thank you! I have just one clarification, though. If say, I want to add a limiter (example: I'll only get id values between 1 to 10), where should I place the WHERE statement? If I place it right before the GROUP BY statement, it reverts back to the original JSON output (missing months that should have 0 value).

Comment: In such a case put the check in the ON clause of the LEFT OUTER JOIN. Also note that if the range of dates is fairly static then you could have a table of months / years (instead of using the sub query) which would probably be more efficient.